# Servicio no funciona en android 7+

Tags: android

Tengo un servicio en background que dura aproximadamente 5 minutos y ejecuta X métodos cada X tiempo cada uno, es necesario que esos tiempos se cumplan y vayan consecutivos.

El problema es que android 7 mata el servicio al "apagar la pantalla".

Puedo hacer esto con un JobScheduler? (el servicio tiene timers dentro), o debería usar un servicio foreground?

Ejemplo de mi servicio:

```
public class MyServide extends Service {

    class MyBinder extends Binder {
        MyServide getService() {
            return MyServide.this;
        }
    }

    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            Observable.timer(randomTime), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(aLong -> {
                   //random code
                });
        }
        return MyBinder;
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿cual es el código? por : #El problema es que android 7 mata el servicio al "apagar la pantalla", me parece es configuración del mismo.

Comment: @Jorgesys sabes si un jobscheduler puede abrir la app y ejecutar un servicio en foreground? creo que no es necesario el código ya que es un servicio normal, pero si crees que es realmente necesario lo pongo mañana, un saludo

Comment: Lo que deseas se puede realizar pero me parece que el código es necesario por ejemplo tu servicio usa START_NOT_STICKY?

Comment: Puedes probar de usar la libreria JobSchedulerCompat https://github.com/Doist/JobSchedulerCompat lo que no ser es como indica @jorgesys al apagar la pantalla si lo pausa, tambien creo el minimo es cada 15min ysu precisión no es 100%

Comment: @Webserveis le echaré un ojo, he probado esta: https://github.com/evernote/android-job pero no me deja crear un webview por el contexto y el UI thread, a ver si la que tu me has pasado me deja hacer esto, respecto al código lo subiré más tarde cuando saque tiempo libre... gracias

Comment: @Jorgesys acabo de añadir el tipo de servicio que tengo

Comment: @pcg26 sobreescribe el método que comento y agrega la propiedad ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que tu servicio continue ejecutandose en background y no importante si cierras la aplicación debes sobreescribir el método `onStartCommand()` usando la propiedad **START_STICKY** :

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

Es decir que si cerramos la aplicación que inicio este servicio, el servicio continua su funcionamiento.

En el caso de detener el servicio esta propiedad no afecta el poder detenerlo.

```
public class MyServide extends Service {

...
...

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido de ayuda, ahora tengo otra duda que igual me puedes ayudar... podría ejecutar este servicio a través de una push notification? suponiendo que el usuario tiene la app cerrada
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49309161/can-a-jobscheduler-execute-a-foreground-service

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTA**: Si tu aplicación está orientada al nivel de API 26 o un nivel superior, el >sistema impone restricciones en la ejecución de servicios en segundo plano cuando la >aplicación misma no se encuentra en primer plano. La mayoría de las veces, es mejor que >tu aplicación use una tarea programada.

**FUENTE**: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es